# tumblr oembed support for video sites - whitelist?

Tags: video, tumblr, oembed

tumblr supports copy&pasting links from a number of videos sites providing oembed json / xml files (youtube, vimeo, dailymotion) but seems to ignore others (screenr, ted.com) although those sites offer valid oembed files as well.

as there is no information in the tumblr docs / in their google group / on stackoverlow on this topic: what's the deciding factor? is there a whitelist of providers and if so, who is the person to get in touch with for getting on this whitelist?

many thanks!

p.s.: being an embed.ly provider (http://embed.ly/embed/features/providers) does not seem to be enough.

Comment: That is a very good and valid question. It maybe worth contacting support (http://www.tumblr.com/help) and asking directly. Please let us know your findings.

Comment: Thanks. Jep, I've already made a post in their google group but got no answer so far. I'll keep this question updated in case there are any relevant news.

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate it. Handy for documentation.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe they just do it for well known websites, and do testing to make sure things work well before adding a new provider.